# Ruby: How do I include methods from a Module into a subclass of ActiveModel::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, rspec3

I'm trying to include a method from a helper module into an `ActiveModel::Serializer` subclass but for some reason the method is not showing up.

Here's my simple helper module:

```
module Helpers
  module Serialisers
    def enforce_zulu_time(attribute)
      define_method(attribute) do
        object.send(attribute).utc.iso8601 unless object.try(attribute).nil?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here's my test serialiser

```
class TestSerialiser < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include Helpers::Serialisers
  attributes :updated_at

  enforce_zulu_time :updated_at
end
```

and my simple object to serialise

```
class TestItem
  include ActiveModel::SerializerSupport
  attr_reader :updated_at
  def initialize
    @updated_at = Time.now.utc
  end
end
```

and my test

```
describe Helpers::Serialisers do
  let(:item)       { TestItem.new }
  let(:serialiser) { TestSerialiser.new(item) }
  subject          { serialiser.attributes }

  it { expect(subject[:updated_at]).to be_zulu_time}
end
```

results in

```
`<class:TestSerialiser>': undefined method `enforce_zulu_time' for TestSerialiser:Class (NoMethodError)
```

However if I just do this in my `TestSerialiser` instead

```
class TestSerialiser < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :updated_at

  ['updated_at'].each do |attribute|
    define_method(attribute) do
      object.send(attribute).utc.iso8601 unless object.send(attribute).blank?
    end
  end
end
```

it all works fine.

Why is my `enforce_zulu_time` method not being included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `include Helpers::Serialisers` with `extend Helpers::Serialisers` since you expect class methods.

Another solution would be to use `ActiveSupport::Concern`, [see doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

---

***Sidenote***

In order to have your code flexible for free, I recommend you to create your own base class for your serializers, like:

```
class BaseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
end
```

Then have all your serializers inherit from it. This way you can add features easily.